# Postsharp: How to set the return value after an exception

Tags: c#, postsharp

Using Postsharp, how do you set the return value after an exception has been thrown?

I thought this would work:

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values/5
        [MyExceptionHandler]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            string value = GetValue(id);
            return value;
        }

        private string GetValue(int id)
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException();
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class MyExceptionHandler : OnExceptionAspect
    {
        public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Continue;
            args.ReturnValue = "Error Getting Value";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.

You need to Return from the function, not continue.

```
    public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        args.FlowBehavior = FlowBehavior.Return;
        args.ReturnValue = "Error Getting Value";
    }
```